# Simple present or present continuous?

Tags: tenses

It____(rain) frequently in London.
This is the sentence that I am confused with. I have been told that with 'permanent' ideas comes simple present and with 'temporary ' ideas comes present continuous. So is it wrong if I wrote :it is raining frequently in London? I wrote this keeping in mind that raining is not a permanent thing. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

At this situation, the sentence is more suitable for simple present rather than present continuous.

Let's see the condition for using simple present and present continuous

### SIMPLE PRESENT

-Habit/fact

-Permanent situations

-Future events which is in a part of a timetable

-Talks about an event in books/plays/films

### Present Continuous

-Event which are happening at the moment

-Temporary situations/Situation which changes slowly

-Temporary/new/annoying habits

-100% sure of a future plan

-Talks about an event in pictures/photos

Now, let's see the situation here. We can see that the keyword here is "frequently" means always/fact. So, I won't consider it as a temporary situation but instead I think it's more like a fact. Thus, it's more suitable to use simple present.

Comment: Oh I see so is there a keyword in every sentence which we should note to check which tense to use. How are we sure that it's a fact?

Comment: In what situation you use the word "frequently"?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get what you meant?

Comment: Let take it this way, frequently and always have the same meaning. Now let's see how you use the word "always"

Comment: I always play basketball every Sunday

Comment: So, is it more like a habit/fact or temporary situation to you?

Comment: Frequently and often have the same meaning but I don't think frequently and always has the same meaning.

Comment: What you said is true in the example always is more like habbit but here we are talking about frequently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19359/discussion-between-simon-nail-it-and-shonima-nandakumar).

Answer (score 0):

If you say "It rains frequently in London" you talk about a fact and not about  what is going on at the moment. For facts simple present is the normal thing.