# What's the difference between "watches" and "watching" in this sentence

Tags: differences

> Lisa **watches** movies every Sunday.

and

> Lisa **is watching** movies every Sunday.

Comment: The continuous present is particularly idiomatic in Indian English, for example "I am having a bus ticket", compare with "I have a bus ticket".

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think that's only for "non-native-Anglophone" Indians - it probably wouldn't be used or endorsed by the tiny number of native Anglophones in India. In effect, such use of the continuous in India is really a "shibboleth" identifying non-native Anglophones. I very much doubt the usage would actually be taught (as "correct") in any "reputable" Indian schools.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not sure about non-native Anglophones in India. I think in India they sometimes use the progressive  differently than in the West.

Comment: That type of phrasing can often be seen in StackOverflow questions, and although the profile might not indicate the sub-continent, it's a 'tell'. *"I am having a doubt about..."*

Comment: @Lambie: Half the houses in my road contain at least one person born in India, and even if they've lived here many decades, none of them sound like "native Anglophones" to me (different story with the next generation, obviously). It may be that those Indians who *choose* to come to the UK are particularly careful about this *particular* aspect of "IE" (it won't take them long to notice that misuse of the continuous is *very* noticeable to the natives, and liable to be mocked!).

Comment: The examples in this question are not specific to Indian English, as "I am having a doubt" is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are not getting what I am saying: a lot of Indians speak very good English and they **use the progressive tense differently**.  And it is acceptable in India.

Comment: The implications of using the present continuous construction and the present simple are compared and contrasted at [simple present or present continuous](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212903/simple-present-or-present-continuous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a nuanced difference.

> Lisa watches movies every Sunday.

It is Lisa's routine to watch movies every Sunday.

> Lisa is watching movies every Sunday.

Recently Lisa has taken up watching movies on Sunday.

Compare:

> Lisa babysits to earn some spending money.
>
> Lisa is babysitting for the vicar and his wife.

The simple present can express what someone does on a regular basis. The continuous can express what someone has been doing *lately* or what they are doing "these days".